# How to integrate this : $\int \frac{x^2+\cos^2 x}{1+x^2}\csc^2xdx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate :

$\int \frac{x^2+\cos^2x}{1+x^2}\csc^2xdx$

I am not getting any clue how to move further, request you to please provide hint, will be of great help.

Thanks..

Comment: but that was $cosec^2x$ not cosecx dx$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^2+\cos^2x}{1+x^2}\csc^2xdx&=\int \frac{x^2+(1-\sin^2x)}{1+x^2}\csc^2xdx\\
&=\int \frac{(x^2+1)-\sin^2x)}{1+x^2}\csc^2xdx\\
&=\int\bigg[1-\frac{\sin^2x}{1+x^2}\bigg]\csc^2xdx\\
&=\int\bigg[\csc^2x-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\bigg]dx\\
&=-\cot x-\arctan x+C
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{x^2+\cos^2x}{1+x^2} \csc^2x \\
&= \frac{x^2+ 1- \sin^2x}{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sin^2x}\\
&= \frac{1}{\sin^2x} - \frac{1}{1+x^2}.
\end{align}$$
These two terms can be integrated easily.

Answer (score 0):

Before integrating, let's do some changes

$$\frac{(x^2+\cos^2 x)\csc^2x}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^2\csc^2x+\cos^2 x\csc^2x}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^2\csc^2x+\cot^2 x}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^2\csc^2x+\csc^2 x-1}{1+x^2}=\frac{-1+(1+x^2)\csc^2x}{1+x^2}=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\csc^2x.$$

But

$$\int -\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=-\arctan x+C$$

and

$$\int \csc^2xdx=-\cot x+C.$$

So

$$\int \frac{(x^2+\cos^2 x)\csc^2x}{1+x^2}dx=-\arctan x-\cot x+C.$$